# Extrair texto de imagem sem usar Tesseract

Tags: python

Tô querendo extrair um valor de uma imagem com um script Python, porém, a principal solução sugerida é o Tesseract, que infelizmente não consigo implementar, já tentei de diversas formas. Gostaria então de saber se existe outra ferramenta mais simples pra executar essa tarefa com Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O termo para isto provavelmente é OCR, o que pode ajudar a encontrar outras soluções (existem outros termos e até soluções), mas provavelmente você esqueceu de instalar o `PIL` ou não soube como instalar o `pytesser`

O pytesser pode ser instalado manualmente:

- https://code.google.com/archive/p/pytesser/

Ou via pip:

```
pip install pytesseract
```

Mas antes de instalar ele você deve instalar o:

- http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/

E um exemplo da breve documentação/readme:

```
from pytesser import *

image = Image.open('fnord.tif') # Abre uma imagem usando PIL

print image_to_string(image)
```

Ou

```
from pytesser import *

print image_file_to_string('fnord.tif')
```

Claro que essa lib esta sem atualização desde 2007, logo penso que deve ter uma série de problemas com Python3 (ou nem ser compatível, não pude testar), então a solução que creio que a maioria irá lhe informar é usar o [opencv](https://opencv.org/), no caso existe uma pequena lib pronta que pode instalar via PIP:

- https://pypi.org/project/simple-opencv-ocr/

Ela foi inspirada nas soluções propostas em https://stackoverflow.com/q/9413216/1518921, não estou certo se a lib em si reconhece apenas números, como foi proposto na pergunta original, mas se o intuito é adaptar ou até aprender esta ai alguns exemplos que pode estudar.

Comment: Obrigado, pela resposta, dei uma boa estudada nesses e outros exemplos. Percebi que terei de utilizar o Tesseract mesmo. Até o momento não encontrei uma solução mais simples.